# IntelliJ strange behavior

Tags: java, git, maven, intellij-idea

I've installed 30 day trial of IntelliJ 15.0.2 and cloned my project using git (I've created this project in community version). Project compiles (maven), runs, works. But new IntelliJ does not underline my errors, misspellings etc. When I wanted to commit, IntelliJ shows big number of errors, mostly on imports, as it can't resolve them. All dependencies are inside pom.xml. Once again, there were no errors in community version of IntelliJ. Ultimate version builds project just fine, but doesn't underline any errors and shows almost every import as unsolvable. What could go wrong? How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Build -> Make Project`. After that errors should be visible in the project tree and in the specific project files.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to mark the source dir, by right-clicking it on the project tab and select mark directory as -> source root

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have a correct project sdk set in modules configuration. If IJ doesn't found any classes, jdk classes included, probably there is no sdk set.

You can also try to invalidate caches (in File menu) and rebuild project

Answer (score 0):

I have faced with strange behaviour of Intelij Idea after update (syntax highlight stopped working). If you want to understand what is going on with yor Idea and can not quickly find an answer in internet, just go to Log files (for Mac OS the path is

```
~/Library/Logs/IntelliJIdea< your version>
```

List all files in that directory

```
ls -la
```

in terminal and find the latest one. Usually it should be idea.log (without numbers, logs with numbers identify logs for previous days). View that log. If that log contains a lot of ERRORS, try to find the reason (you can just type

```
grep "ERROR" idea.log
```

in terminal to find all lines that contain errors). Usually log files shouldn't contain errors, just info and warnings.

In my case syntax highlight stopped working. The log looked like
[image]

You can see here that error is in plugins that called like haxe.

I found that plugin in my idea, uninstalled it and idea started working properly. I investigated the log after and what I have seen there:
[image]

You can see just INFO in new rows.

Investigating a log can be really useful if you can not find the rootcase of your problem quickly in the internet. I hope it can help you even if it can be quite tricky.

Good luck!